# running UWSim commands in ROS

Tags: ros

Where can I find a good documentation about the UWSim in ROS. Actually having the source files is not enough and it is actually hard to follow all the functions. for example, how can I use these command correctly :

& rosrun UWSim gotoAbsolutePosition   0 0 0 0 0 0

I know that there is a node 'gotoAbsolutePosition' in the Package 'UWSim' and I knwo the variables, but I cannot set the two topics properly.

Comment: You may want to check out [the UWSim wiki page](http://ros.org/wiki/UWSim) or ask your question on [the ROS forum](http://answers.ros.org/questions/).

Comment: There is no such help in the wiki page, but at ROS forum maybe you are right.

Answer (score 1):

The primary entry point for UWSim ROS documentation is at: https://wiki.ros.org/uwsim
This has the basic commands for running it too.

There are example programs such as gotoAbsolutePosition which are mostly thin wrappers on the ROS api for convenience.

You can find all the examples of using the interface here: https://github.com/uji-ros-pkg/underwater_simulation/tree/melodic-devel/uwsim/interface_examples

And it's main documentation wiki is at: http://www.irs.uji.es/uwsim/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page

With a guide for interacting with the simulator on this subpage: http://www.irs.uji.es/uwsim/wiki/index.php?title=First_steps:_Interacting_with_UWSim